# How do I set default settings for Datetimepicker?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I have multiple calendar inputs set up with Bootstrap Datetimepicker: http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/.

I have created an object containing some overwrites:

```
DatetimepickerDefaults = {
    icons: {
        time: 'fa fa-clock-o',
        date: 'fa fa-calendar',
        up: ' fa fa-angle-up',
        down: 'fa fa-angle-down',
        previous: 'fa fa-angle-left',
        next: 'fa fa-angle-right',
        today: 'fa fa-crosshairs',
        clear: 'fa fa-trash',
        close: 'fa fa-times'
    }
}
```

that I want to apply to all of the calendar inputs. So now when I want to init a plugin I write:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker(DatetimepickerDefaults);
```

The problem is that some of the inputs need to have some special settings, like format: 'LT' so when I init them, I write:

```
$('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({
    icons: {
        time: 'fa fa-clock-o',
        date: 'fa fa-calendar',
        up: ' fa fa-angle-up',
        down: 'fa fa-angle-down',
        previous: 'fa fa-angle-left',
        next: 'fa fa-angle-right',
        today: 'fa fa-crosshairs',
        clear: 'fa fa-trash',
        close: 'fa fa-times'
    },
    format: 'LT'
});
```

so I have to repeat this default settings all over again. Is there any way to make it default for all of the plugin instances?

Comment: How much genres like that?

Comment: @webmaster, there are dozen of unique setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set it as a function like:

```
function.DatetimepickerDefaults = function(field, value) {
    var retVal = {
    icons: {
        time: 'fa fa-clock-o',
        date: 'fa fa-calendar',
        up: ' fa fa-angle-up',
        down: 'fa fa-angle-down',
        previous: 'fa fa-angle-left',
        next: 'fa fa-angle-right',
        today: 'fa fa-crosshairs',
        clear: 'fa fa-trash',
        close: 'fa fa-times'
    }};
    if (field) {
        retVal[field] = value;
    }
    return retVal;
}
```

And use it like:

```
$('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker(DatetimepickerDefaults());
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker(DatetimepickerDefaults("format", "LT"));
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker(DatetimepickerDefaults("format", "LT2"));
//And etc...
```

You can use lists for more values, I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

This is a more compact and convenient version of [@webmaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1201725/webmaster)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42177091/4306828), taking advantage of [`jQuery.extend()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/) method.

```
// defaults
function DatetimepickerDefaults(opts) {
    return $.extend({},{
        sideBySide: true,
        ignoreReadonly: true,
        showClose: true,
        toolbarPlacement: 'top'
    }, opts);
}

// usage
$('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker(DatetimepickerDefaults({
    sideBySide: false,
    showClear: true
}));
```

You can again give an object of settings and those will merge with and if necessary overwrite the default settings.